# Cannot Modify Headers Information - Wordpress IDX

Tags: php, wordpress, idx

I have located the line that is the culprit from the Header Error line:

*Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/prissy/public_html/wp-content/themes/tortuga/header.php:11) in /home/prissy/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dsidxpress/client.php on line 483*

The 11 line is the "language attributes" php line.

```
<?php
/**
* The header for our theme
* @package Tortuga
*/
; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
```

This error does not show except on the listing pages that are rendered from the IDX plugin. I can't see what I need to change here. I checked the white space at the bottom of functions.php and wp-config.php and it looks fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The file: `/home/prissy/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dsidxpress/client.php on line 483` wants to send data after the theme has been set up and the header is already spitting out it's HTML.
So my guess would be that the hook on which the plugin is trying to change headers is being called too late. The hook `init` or `plugins_loaded` might be a better hook.

All this is of course only helpful if you want to edit the plugin. Otherwise find a different plugin which is a bit better developed...

Comment: Ok thanks. So I switched themes and it worked without the error. So it seems the theme I am using and the plugin aren't communicating. Guess I'll choose a different theme